# React native identify a boolean within an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am trying to make an app(IOS and Android) for ads and I want to be able to go into the objects of my ads and identify a boolean and if it is true do one thing and something else otherwise.

[Here are the objects of an ad:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAZEu.jpg)

I want to go into the object and if the "ReceiveHelp" is true i want the code to execute say blue as backgroundcoulor otherwise red. The problem is I don't know how to go into the object and identify the boolean props only.

```
   export const publicAdFetch = () => {
     return (dispatch) => {
      firebase.database().ref('/users').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  const usersData = snapshot.val();
     let sortedAdds = Object.keys(usersData).reduce((prev, userId) => {
   let ads = usersData[userId].ads;
   ads = Object.keys(ads).map(key => {
     return { ...ads[key], id: key };
     });
  return prev.concat(ads);
 }, [])
.sort((a, b) => (b.time - a.time));
```

this is the code I currently have to put everything into an array and then sort by time. But I have no idea how to just see if the boolean is true or false

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for a boolean with [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```js
const yourObjArray = [
      {desc: "fdf", price: "rrr", receiveHelp: true},
      {desc: "ccc", price: "254", receiveHelp: 351},
      {desc: "aaa", price: "gdg", receiveHelp: false},
      {desc: "aaa", price: "gdg", receiveHelp: "charlie"},
      {desc: "feee", price: "jth", receiveHelp: true},
    ];
    
yourObjArray.forEach(obj => console.log("The type is: ", typeof obj.receiveHelp));
```

Once you know if the `receiveHelp` is a boolean you can check for true or false easily with `if()`:

```js
const receiveHelp = true;

if (typeof receiveHelp === 'boolean') {
   if (receiveHelp) { // This equals to if (receiveHelp === true)
      console.log("this is true: ", receiveHelp);
   } else { // else false
      console.log("this is false: ", receiveHelp);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rodius

You're help gave me some inspiration!
I solved it but doing:

```
let iftrue = '#666';
if (this.props.callbackFromParent.receiveHelp) {
   iftrue = '#ff0';
```

and then in my styles for the ad i had "iftrue", didn't realize it was so simple that ".receiveHelp" was enough to go into the object to check on the values.

Comment: You can do it in one line with: `const color = this.props.callbackFromParent.receiveHelp ? '#ff0' : '#666'`. Glad I could help.